# How do I generate 8 different random numbers in python?

Tags: python, random, ascii

I'm trying to write an encryption program that generates 8 different random numbers and converts them to ASCII.  If possible I'd like to use the 'random' function in python, but welcome other help.

So far my code for generating the numbers is to assign a value to a different run of the `random.randint()` function 8 different times, the problem is that this is sloppy. A friend said to use `random.sample(33, 126, 8)` but I can't get this to work.

Any help is extremely welcome.

Comment: Should / shouldn't values be unique?

Comment: As long as the values are not all the same it doesn't matter, they should have been independently generated

Comment: "_The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes._"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass  `xrange` with your upper and lower bound to sample:

```
from random import sample

print(sample(xrange(33, 126),8))
```

An example output:

```
[49, 107, 83, 44, 34, 84, 111, 69]
```

Or `range` for python3:

```
 print(sample(range(33, 126),8))
```

Example output:

```
 [72, 70, 76, 85, 71, 116, 95, 96]
```

That will give you unique numbers.

If you want 8 variables:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h =  sample(range(33, 126), 8)
```

If you want ascii you can `map(chr..)`:

```
from random import sample

print map(chr,sample(xrange(33, 126), 8))
```

Example output:

```
['Z', 'i', 'v', '$', ')', 'V', 'h', 'q']
```

Comment: Thanks very much! just quickly, how would I then split them individually and assign them to be independent variables?

Comment: just unpack, you want 8 variables yes?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot about unpacking!

Comment: @Matt123 Though unpacking is the right way, Why don't you just use the list as such and the elements using list indexes, i.e `l = sample(range(33, 126),8)` and `l[0]`, `l[1]`, etc .. ?

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea, certainly more efficient for creating variables

Comment: Okay , what are the odds of getting this result when i run the code
[103, 49, 72, 70, 85, 44, 47, 105]

Answer (score 2):

Using `random.sample` is technically not what you want - the values are not independent since after you choose the first number (from 93 options) you only have 92 options for the second number and so on.

If you're ok with that you can use Padraic's answer.

If `n` (in your case `n = 8`) is much smaller than `N` (in your case `N = 126-33 = 93`) this should be fine, but the *correct* answer will be

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [random.randint(93, 126) for _ in xrange(8)]
```

edit: More importantly, if you decide to increase `n` to a state where `n > N`, you'll get a `ValueError`

Comment: Thank you, I will probably use this if it does truly give random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to pick 8 random ASCII characters in the range [33..126], you can do that directly. First, ASCII characters in that range is called `string.printable`. You can use the `random.sample` function to pick out 8 from there:

```
import string
import random

result = random.sample(string.printable, 8)
```

`result` is now a list of 8 random printable characters.

Comment: That is not the same as `xrange(33, 126))`, the range for printable is 9,10,11,12,13,32-126

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a generator. It will only work if you use python 2.5 or above.

```
from random import randint

def randnums(number, startnum=0, endnum=10):
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        yield randint(startnum, endnum)

print list(randnums(8, endnum=100))
```